# Set customdata in the receiver

Tags: chromecast

I am writing a receiver where I send the receiver user submitted data to start. I would like to set a flag once the receiver has received this message that the sender can see so that if the sender reconnects it does not prompt the user for the data a second time.

I saw in the docs a customData field in the session object that is supposedly set by the receiver but I cannot see where the receiver actually sets this field.

CustomData in the api: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.Session#customData

Does any one know how to set this field or a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the customData in the receiver status message is not supported and we will remove it from the documentation in a future update.

We recommend that you create your own namespace channel for your custom data or you can use the  customData of the media namespace status .